# OpenLayers 4 Draw circle on map. Circle radius in meters and Map using latitude and longitude

Tags: openlayers

I'm not sure why, but the resources available is seems very specific to each scenario and won't help some one else or for a different version.

What I'm trying to do is this: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/custom-circle-render.html. But the example does not seem to work. Further to this, I'd like to draw a circle where the point is specified in degrees(EPSG:4326) and the radius in meters. My map's projection is also EPSG:4326. I have ended up trying to simplify to the following:

```
    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: document.getElementById('map'),
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 5
        }),
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            }),
            new ol.layer.Vector({
                projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                source: vectorSource,
            }),
        ],
    });

function MapAddRadius() {
        var circle = new ol.geom.Circle(
            ol.proj.transform([0, 0], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
            10
        );
        var circleFeature = new ol.Feature(circle);
        vectorSource.addFeature(circleFeature);
    }
```

This does draw a circle, but it is not the correct size. This leads me to believe that I'm using the wrong projection as the size does correlate to degrees instead of meters. Or there are functions I am unaware of that makes this easier. I know that precision could be an issue, but I'm drawing small circles, like less than 1km, so I'm not too worried about it.

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: What do you mean by [the example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/custom-circle-render.html) does not seem to work?  [It works for me](http://geocodezip.com/OL_6.5.0_custom-circle-render.html) (at least I get the same result as in the documentation)

Comment: Are you trying to do something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_6.5.0_geocodeSanDiego_circlesExample.html) (draws two circles, one the native `ol.geom.Circle` with a radius of 4000, the other a circular polygon with a radius of 4000 meters)

Comment: @geocodezip It will not work with OpenLayers 4, there was a condition missing the code which handled the custom rendering https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/11838/files#diff-bccd604f05dbb5bfcb22672192beddd9764d6fcd6860ee0f06b7d4f69111ca29

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks, should have been a hint, but it turns out that it did not work as I was using an older version. It's weird, but NuGet packages only has up until V4. I had to manually update the version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ol.geom.Circle` requires coordinates and radius to be in the same units, and all geometry must be in the view projection.  The custom renderer used in the example is specific to Circle geometry and due to an omission in earlier versions will only work with OpenLayers 6.  If you must have a Circle geometry in EPSG:4326 view and radius in meters try

```
    var circle = new ol.geom.Circle(
        ol.proj.transform([lon, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        radius
    ).transform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
```

or

```
    var circle = new ol.geom.Circle(
        [lon, lat],
        radius / ol.proj.getPointResolution('EPSG:4326', 1, [lon, lat], 'm')
    )
```

The second method will scale the radius to approximate to true distance on the ground at northern and southern latitudes.

Comment: Yip, Version issue. Thanks so much! It's weird, but NuGet packages only has up until V4. I had to manually update the version.